# AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free only on Release archive

Tags: ios, swift, memory, video-toolbox

I have created an example of my class: https://github.com/ChoadPet/H.264-Decoding

When I build my application with `DEBUG` configuration everything is working **fine**, but when I archive `RELEASE` it's crashing on this line:

```
let status = VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame(session,
                                               sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer,
                                               flags: defaultDecodeFlags,
                                               frameRefcon: nil,
                                               infoFlagsOut: nil)
```

With `Address Sanitizer` enable I got this error:
`Thread 9: Use of deallocated memory`

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free
(.../Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x1a1f4) in wrap_memmove
...
(if you need more crash info, let me know)
```

Without: `Thread 12: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x107dd0020)`

---

I do understand that there is some memory that was freed and it accesses by `VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame` method, but I can't find any address with hex, and I don't understand how this is working perfectly with the `DEBUG` build.
Before this method, `session` and `sampleBuffer` are successfully created(initialized).

**Is there are some project settings I can change to `DEBUG configuration` which can cause the crash? Or somebody can point me out on a code issue?**

Thank you!

Comment: If `sampleBuffer` is an optional, maybe you could use a `guard` to unwrap it before using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `Optimization Level` for Release archive to the same as for Debug - `No Optimization[-Onone]` hide the problem, but changing build configuration is not the right way to resolve this kinda problem. Also, the problem was not exactly in `sampleBuffer`. The problem was in `blockBufferOut` parameter, which goes into `sampleBuffer` later. I will update the repo source code, so the community can see changes clearly.

So I had before this logic:

```
// 1. Creating blockBuffer from `bufferPointer`
localFrame.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { bufferPointer in
   // I should write everything in this body,
   // since bufferPointer would be released after the closure
   // and so, it will be released from bufferBlock
}

// 2. I called this method, which is creating `sampleBuffer`
CMSampleBufferCreateReady

// 3. I called this method, which is decode frame with session and sampleBuffer 
VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame

/* 
and on this line, it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, 
because the sample wasn't valid anymore, because 
on step 1, bufferPointer only valid inside body closure, 
so it's release after block when I created sampleBuffer
and later decode it.


This is even pointed by documentation:

Parameters

body
Closure with an UnsafeMutableBufferPointer parameter that points to the
contiguous storage for the array. If no such storage exists, it is created. If
the body has a return value, that value is also used as the return value for the
withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(_:) method. The pointer argument is valid only for
the duration of the method’s execution.
*/
```

**Summary: if you operate on bufferPointer, do all operations inside a closure.**

Answer (score 0):

Added to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63227669/3499279) provided by @vpoltave, I found using a dispatch queue after the samplebuffer creation used to give me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error or if you turn on address sanitiser, then it would error out in the `com.apple.coremedia.videomediaconverter` with `Use of deallocated memory`. Suggestion is to enqueue the raw data instead of the created buffers. For me the source was a frame in elementary format coming in callbacks.